# Zend Studio doesn't recognize php

Tags: php, zend-studio

Why the Zend Studio doesn't recognize some functions?

[image] [image]

Comment: I experience the same. Did you find a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov the problem was the php preferences in Zend Studio. Now I am using PHP Storm, it is a good solution for open source software analyst.

Comment: By any chance, do you remember where to find these preferences? Thanks.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov Look and vote my solution. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here how I have solved the issue:

Under Preferences in the Zend Studio application I have added the correct path of the interpreter. In my case: /usr/bin/php

Then I have closed and open again the Zend Studio and the issue is disappeared.

**Zend Studio Preferences**

[image]

Comment: Strangely I couldn't make it work for all my projects but I guess this is the correct solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: on my machine running the php.exe from within a bundled 5.5 or 5.6 in CLI returns a error, which might be the underlying issue.

see Zend Forums http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=128193&p=253078#p253078

Answer (score -1):

It recognizes them, it's just a notice that you should use global namespace for these functions:

```
\is_numeric($id);
\print_r($event);
```

`empty()` is not function, but language construct.

It's likely possible to exclude these notices somewhere in the settings.

Comment: Hi @Marek no the "\" doesn't correct the issue. Look at the screenshot.